# mark complete from another context

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have an Account form.

In the interactions tab I have the sub grid for meetings.

I have added the new button to this Sub-grid, 'Complete the Meeting'.

I want to trigger the 'Mark Complete' button of the Meeting form from here.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Why dont you use OOB button in subgrid ? Can you show some screenshot?

Comment: @ArunVinoth There is no OOB button option in Ribbon Editor

Comment: @ArunVinoth https://ibb.co/KXXw9rL

Comment: Can you use Activity subgrid instead of Meeting subgrid - then you can see 'Mark Complete' button? check and let me know

Comment: @ArunVinoth I can't see it

Comment: any follow up questions?

Answer (score 1):

My first choice would be using Activities subgrid instead of Appointments. I just verfied as below.

[image]

If that wont work for you for any reasons, then custom ribbon button is a good choice. You have to customize the command of your custom button to use javascript command, then [pass the selected IDs from subgrid to ribbon button command](https://d365demystified.com/2020/06/21/pass-selected-rows-guids-to-ribbon-button-in-d365-ribbon-workbench/) and iterate the IDs for [updating Appointment records](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50387416) using `Xrm.Webapi` in javascript function.

Comment: I'm stuck on the 'Updating' part

Comment: @magicalKhachapuri edit the question and show the code. I can help you

Comment: @magicalKhachapuri This should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50387416